# Java RMI - jar on NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, rmi

I have an RMI server that is using a class from another project. I have imported the jar of the other project as library on the RMI and it works fine on netbeans. Although when I run the RMI Server from the .jar generated by netbeans, I am getting `classnotfoundexception`for the class imported.

```
Any suggestions why it would be running inside netbeans, but the jar isn't working?
```

Also I am not sure if it was the right choice but on the RMI I have checked " used dedicated library folder" since the other project is very small.

Also note I am importing the server on the other project too, so that it can use the remote interface.( although I guess this has nothing to do with the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you launch your rmi server you put in the classpath also the jar with the other class?

Try to launch the jar from command prompt:

```
java -jar -classpath rmiserver.jar:lib/other.jar rmiserver.jar
```

Comment: I just double click to launch the jar. The libraries are in a separate folder called lib that are on the same place with the server jar. This is how it generated from NetBeans and other projects work ..

Comment: Try to launch the server from command prompt, as I put in the example.

Comment: I think what was causing the problem was a space on the name of the .jar file. I renamed the project but that didn't change the name of the jar for some reason so I manually changed it. After that the server worked.

Comment: Would you know any way of having everything in one jar including the libraries ? So that when I send the program to someone he won't need to have those two things in same place , just one jar

Answer (score 0):

If you've built your project with a standard netbeans project (instead of a maven one), you'll see a lib directory underneath the dist directory where the final jar is built. Netbeans will build the manifest in the main jar file such that it will look for the dependent jars in that lib directory which is relative to the location of the built jar. So if you put your built jar in one directory, copy the lib folder to that directory, then launch it like so:

```
java -jar my.jar
```

e.g

```
+ folder
|   my.jar
+-+ lib
  | other.jar
```